# How to get maximum element of array from index a to index b?

Tags: c

I keep getting the error

> ```
> format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int (*)(int *, int, int)'.
> printf("%d", get_max);
> ```

I'm new to pointers and coding C in general and still haven't fully grasped the language yet. I hope you can be patient in helping me fix my code and letting me understand why such error appeared.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//get maximum element of array from index a to index b, inclusive

int get_max(int *array, int a, int b);


int get_max(int *array, int a, int b)
{
    int max;

    for (int j=0; j<=(b-a); j++) {

        array[j] = *(array+j+a);

        if(array[j] > array[j+1])
           max = array[j]; 
    }   

    return max;
}


int main() {

    int array[] = {1,4,-1,2,5};
    int *arr;
    int i;
    arr = array;

    printf(" PRINT ARRAY \n");

       for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {

          arr[i] = *(arr + i);

          printf("%d  ",arr[i]);
       }

    get_max(array,0,2),

    printf("MAX: %d", get_max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `get_max` before printing, and then try and print the function pointer. You probably want `get_max(array,0,2)` in the `printf` - that's where the error is.

Comment: When you write just `get_max` in the `printf` call, you are passing a pointer to the `get_max` function to `printf()`, and you can't print function pointers with the `%d` format.  The notation `int (*)(int *, int, int)` is the minimal notation for a pointer to function, used in casts (and some compiler error messages).

Comment: Why did you write the self-assignment `arr[i] = *(arr + i);` in the printing loop?  It doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Note that where your function is _defined before use_ as in this case,  the prototype declaration is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fundamental problem is that you are passing the function pointer to `printf` rather than the function return value:

You have:

```
get_max(array,0,2),

printf("MAX: %d", get_max);
```

when you need something like:

```
int max = get_max(array, 0, 2 );

printf( "MAX: %d", max ) ;
```

Use of the comma operator rather then the semi-colon statement terminator in your `get_max()` call was presumably a typo too?

To explain the diagnostic:

```
format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int (*)(int *, int, int)'.
                        ^                               ^
                       (1)                             (2)
```

- <sup>(1)</sup> The `%d` format specifier expects an int argument.
- <sup>(2)</sup> You passed an pointer to a function returning `int` and taking arguments of type `int *, int, int`

Even then your `get_max()` function is seriously flawed:

- It inspects elements from `0` to `b - a` rather then from `a` to `b`,
- it modifies the array; if `a` is greater than zero, it is not a harmless self-assignment.
- if `a` is zero and `array[a]` is the largest value, `max` is unassigned.

Consider:

```
int get_max( const int* array, int a, int b )
{
    int max = array[a] ;

    for( int i = a + 1; i < b; i++ ) 
    {
        if( array[i] > max )
        {
            max = array[i] ;
        } 
    }   

    return max;
}
```

Comment: Typo `int max = array[i] ;` where `i` should be `a`. Only other thought would be an initial test `if (a > b)` in `get_max` and some diagnostic output to insure the parameter are ascending. Otherwise `max` would simply be `array[a]` and presumed to be the max.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin fixed the typo, thanks. It would be unusual for such a low level function to issue a diagnostic, because in order to make it generic, one cannot assume any particular means available to do that.  An assert perhaps, but such issues are beyond the scope of the question.  Arguably if a is valid, and b not, then array[a] is the largest in the valid range. Garbage in - Garbage out. In this case validation should probably be an application level issue.  If every minor leaf function checked it's arguments rather than assuming preconditions, performance would suffer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin a better design would be to pass a start index and a length, rather than start/end.  Then the index order issue becomes a non problem.

Comment: Agreed, you would hope `a` and `b` would be validated in ascending order before it was called.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I realized soon after and just wasn't able to update this thread. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

In the lines:

```
get_max(array,0,2),
printf("MAX: %d", get_max);
```

`get_max()` function returns maximum value from array and you are not storing value anywhere. You have to store that value, than you can print it.

```
max = get_max(array,0,2);
printf("MAX: %d", max);
```

The format error for:

```
printf("MAX: %d", get_max);
```

is caused because `get_max` is a function pointer and `%d` requires an integer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I think the analysis "your code is perfectly fine" is optimistic.  The code in `get_max()` is not correct; it isn't even really plausible.  Suppose the call is `get_max(array, 1, 3)` — can you explain why it modifies `array[0]` (with the assignment `array[j] = *(array+j+a);`) and still produces the wrong answer?

Comment: if you want to get max element from index a to b, you can simply write the get_max() function in this way.

    `int get_max(int *array, int a, int b) {
    int max=0, j;
    for (j=a; j<b; j++) {
        if(array[j] > array[j+1])
           max = array[j]; 
    }
    return max; } `

Comment: In your revised code (in the comment), I think you should compare `array[j]` with `max`, not `array[j+1]`.

Comment: @Beginner ; Your solution to the broken `get_max()` function should be added to the answer rather than placed in a comment.  The body text does not explicitly ask for that, but it is implied by the question title, so a solution is legitimate in the answer.  SO is not a discussion forum.  Comments are used to improve questions and answers, not to provide them.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I realized soon after and just wasn't able to update this thread. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

The output of `printf("MAX: %d", get_max);` is a garbage value as `get_max` is not a variable but its a function so, in format string only function name which is declared as `int` is passed. To get the return value of`get_max()` function it's better to write the right calling syntax that is `printf("MAX: %d", get_max(array, 0, 2);` which will give you the return value of get_max() function with given arguments.

**NOTE**
**1** fix the typo `get_max(array,0,2),` what is a comma doing there?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I realized soon after and just wasn't able to update this thread. It was also a typo Thank you very much!

Comment: The stray comma is a comma operator; the function call is made and the result discarded before calling `printf`.  It isn't technically wrong, though it isn't what's intended.  I don't understand what you mean by "in format string only function name which is declared as `int` is passed".  What's passed is a pointer to function, but it is passed as an argument, not part of the format string.